# Float table elements using only html/css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-email

I'm trying to write a responsive email template at present so am restricted to using html tables and inline css (without the assistance of javascript or media queries) in order to support as many email clients as possible.

Specifically I'd like to float some elements (either entire tables or internal columns) so that they fill the width available evenly but also drop to the next to the line when the width available isn't large enough to accommodate all text.

This is my first attempt which spaces the elements evenly within the width available: http://jsfiddle.net/aerospatiale/noy7ur7a/.

```
table { 
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    text-align: justify; 
}
table:after {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
table th { 
    vertical-align:top; 
    text-align: center;
    font-weight:normal; 
}

<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>One</th>
        <th>Two</th>
        <th>Three</th>
        <th>Four</th>
        <th>Five</th>
        <th>Six</th>
        <th>Seven</th>
        <th>Eight</th>
        <th>Nine</th>
        <th>Ten</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my second attempt which allows the elements to drop to the next line when necessary but does not evenly distribute the elements within the full width available: http://jsfiddle.net/5qsjn2ys/.

```
table { 
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    text-align: justify; 
}
table th { 
    display: inline-block !important;
    vertical-align:top; 
    text-align: center;
    font-weight:normal; 
}

<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>One</th>
        <th>Two</th>
        <th>Three</th>
        <th>Four</th>
        <th>Five</th>
        <th>Six</th>
        <th>Seven</th>
        <th>Eight</th>
        <th>Nine</th>
        <th>Ten</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to combine both these effects to distribute the elements evenly but also allow them to drop to the next line when the available width is not sufficient?

Note: I realise it's a little unorthodox to use th elements, however it's to combat an Android quirk.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to change to `display:block` for lower screen sizes.

http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/noy7ur7a/2/

Comment: Hey @afelixj, that's definitely the effect that I am after, however I need to achieve it without using the float attribute if possible as it's not supported in Outlook https://newsignature.com/articles/responsive-email-templates-outlook-tips-pitfalls.

Comment: is it possible to split to separate tables?

Comment: Yes, sure! I am restricted to tables but don't mind whether the split occurs at a table or column level.

Comment: Tested with two `th` in a table. [http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/noy7ur7a/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/noy7ur7a/3/).. need wraping table for center alignment now... but `table align="center"` is not widely supported anyway.

Comment: Hi @afelixj, thanks for your help but that solution still seems to rely on float to work.

Comment: you can remove the float for th. I missed to remove it.

Comment: So here is the best approximation I can make to what I want (inline-block and justify aren't even required in this case either) http://jsfiddle.net/aerospatiale/9gzf3tsu. The problem is however that this requires exact widths and media queries. Is there a way to make this floating automatic without these fixed values? Email clients such as gmail and even apple mail ignore media queries so if the originally chosen width doesn't fit to the screen in the gmail client, you are left with the tables in separate rows, stacking to the left without filling the available space.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with tables, and remember to make everything as inline css since gmail strips head-styles. I have done it this way in a few responsive templates i have made. And this can be used across all 42 most common email/web clients.

demo: 
https://jsfiddle.net/aerospatiale/noy7ur7a/

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" style="width: 100%;max-width: 600px;background-color: #eeeeee;">
<tr>
    <td>
        <table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="60" align="center">
                    1
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="60" align="center">
                    2
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="60" align="center">
                    3
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="60" align="center">
                    4
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="60" align="center">
                    5
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="60" align="center">
                    6
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="60" align="center">
                    7
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="60" align="center">
                    8
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="60" align="center">
                    9
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="60" align="center">
                    10
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```